# Are there any hints as to what Kvothe's sword named Folly is about?

Tags: the-kingkiller-chronicle

We know from the 2nd book that it is not the sword Caesura he received from the Adem for it looks completely different and I believe he even said so. I am just hoping I did not miss anything related to it.

Comment: You might try reading the comments to the Kingkiller Re-read on tor.com, as there are some theories there. One that I recall is that it belonged to Cinder (recall the brief description of that sword in their encounter in book one), and that Kvothe killed him and thus obtained his sword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After three reads, I have not picked up any hints about why he named it Folly, if anything the sword named Folly seems more a hint towards what happens in book 3.

Answer (score 7):

My best guess is that it is an inside joke for Kvothe. The most poignant use of the word folly in my opinion is what Abenthy inscribed in the book "Rhetoric and Logic"

> "Kvothe, Defend yourself well at the University. Make me proud. Remember your father's song. Be wary of **folly**. Your friend, Abenthy."